# Losing connection to wifi randomly, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Dell XPS 15 9530

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have been having trouble with my wireless card. Here is what I get from dmesg:

```
A@B:~$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    4.410812] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.948900127.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.461558] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    4.479921] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: base HW address: 90:2e:1c:4a:98:2c
[    4.695410] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0 wlp6s0: renamed from wlan0
[  109.553413] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[  109.553421] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[  109.553482] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000000: 08b18086 00100000 028000c3 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  109.553487] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0708086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[  109.553491] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[  109.553530] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000000: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[  109.553534] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000020: ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
[  109.553541] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[  109.553574] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00100000 00000000 00462031 00002000 00002000 00000014 40000001
[  109.553577] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000020: 0000000f f7900460 00000000
[  109.553581] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.2) config registers:
[  109.553614] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 8c148086 00100407 060400d5 00810010 00000000 00000000 00060600 200000f0
[  109.553618] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: f790f790 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 00100303
[  109.553678] WARNING: CPU: 7 PID: 0 at /build/linux-60XibS/linux-4.15.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:1973 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xea/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[  109.553679] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm bnep arc4 pn544_mei mei_phy pn544 hci nfc joydev intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal iwlmvm intel_powerclamp coretemp dell_laptop kvm_intel dell_smbios_smm dcdbas mac80211 kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul dell_wmi sparse_keymap crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate dell_smbios_wmi intel_rapl_perf dell_smbios input_leds wmi_bmof dell_wmi_descriptor uvcvideo serio_raw videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 rtsx_pci_ms videobuf2_core videodev iwlwifi memstick hid_multitouch btusb media btrtl btbcm btintel snd_hda_codec_hdmi bluetooth cfg80211 snd_hda_codec_realtek ecdh_generic snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm acpi_als kfifo_buf industrialio
[  109.553793] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xea/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[  109.553823]  iwl_read_prph+0x38/0x90 [iwlwifi]
[  109.553834]  iwl_trans_pcie_log_scd_error+0x125/0x1f0 [iwlwifi]
[  109.553848]  ? iwl_pcie_txq_build_tfd+0xe0/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
[  109.553856]  iwl_pcie_txq_stuck_timer+0x46/0x70 [iwlwifi]
[  109.608796] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Queue 10 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [56, 65] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
```

When I grep lsmod, this is what I get,

```
A@B:~$ lsmod | grep iwl
iwlmvm                364544  0
mac80211              778240  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               282624  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              622592  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

This is what I get when I run iwconfig,

```
A@B:~$ iwconfig
enxd8eb97b0f784  no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"my_internet"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point:  3C:1E:04:DC:AA:9D   
      Bit Rate=650 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:44   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

When I look up the network manager state, this is what I get,

```
A@B:~$ cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state 
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

Finally, this is what I get when I look up the following,

```
A@B:~$ lspci | grep Network && uname -a
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev c3)
Linux B 4.15.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 17 15:39:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Some information about my computer:
I run a Dell XPS 15 9530, with an intel i7 CPU and I guess an intel Wireless 7260 card.

Here is something important to note I think. Usually when my computer disconnects from the wireless card (at least I think that is what is going on), then when I run

dmesg | grep iwl, lsmod | grep iwl, and iwconfig, I get nothing, nothing, and "lo   no wireless extention" respectively.

I have tried unloading and reloading iwlconfig via the command modprobe, but it does not help. Furthermore, I tried using the linux kernel 4.15.24 to see if maybe it was an issue with the current kernel. This also did not help.

Searching on forums like this one has led me to try all of these different things. But so far I have not had any success. So this is a direct appeal for help. It is incredibly frustrating not being able to work since I rely on internet access to do my job. May I please get some help? Is there more information required to fix this issue?

Thank you very much!

---

Update (August 8, 2018)

---

I encountered a completely new issue with my computer. This is what I got from dmesg:

```
A@B:~$ dmesg --level=err
[   28.545162] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Hardware error detected.  Restarting.
[   28.545249] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: HW error, resetting before reading
[   28.604079] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[   28.604082] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[   28.604137] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000000: 08b18086 00100406 028000c3 00000000 f7900004 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   28.604140] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0708086 00000000 000000c8 00000000 00000100
[   28.604141] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi device memory mapped registers:
[   28.604187] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000000: 40800000 80000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   28.604189] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000020: 00000001 080003dc 00000144 00000000 80000000 803a0000 80008040 00080046
[   28.604194] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi device AER capability structure:
[   28.604222] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000000: 14010001 00000000 00000000 00462031 00000000 00002000 00000000 00000000
[   28.604224] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: 00000020: 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   28.604226] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwlwifi parent port (0000:00:1c.2) config registers:
[   28.604240] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000000: 8c148086 00100407 060400d5 00810010 00000000 00000000 00060600 200000f0
[   28.604242] iwlwifi 0000:00:1c.2: 00000020: f790f790 0001fff1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000040 00000000 00100303
[   30.796567] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Access time out - failed to enable LP XTAL
[   30.841730] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: Failed to init the card
[   30.843234] wlp6s0: failed to remove key (0, 3c:1e:04:dc:aa:9d) from hardware (-5)
[   30.847718] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: iwl_trans_wait_tx_queues_empty bad state = 0
[   30.848028] wlp6s0: failed to remove key (2, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-5)
```

Comment: did you try steps `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` `sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm``sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi`sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi`

Comment: Yes I did. So, I can unload modprobe and load it again, but I will get an error message. I do have "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" in my iwlwifi.conf file.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  I have now reinstalled the drivers twice.  It'll work for a while and then after a random reboot, it will suddenly lose track of the drivers again.  It's driving me crazy, because every time it happens, I have to wire up to fix it.  And I don't always have access to wired ethernet.